# Timestamp of builds in Teamcity API

Tags: api, teamcity, dashboard, klipfolio

I am trying to get data of my builds from Teamcity and place it into a dashboard I am creating. I am getting most of the data but this thing I am missing is the timestamp of the builds. I have searched alot on internet but cant find it. In teamcity I can see the timestamp of all the builds but it is not available in the timstamp.

All suggestions are appriciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the REST API or the OpenAPI?

Comment: Im using the REST API.

Comment: What timestamp are you looking for? When getting `/app/rest/builds/id:21966`, I see the `build` element contains the `queuedDate`, `startDate`, `finishDate` sub-elements. If those aren't enough, the `triggered` sub-element has the `date` attribute. Have you just overlooked these?

Comment: What is this id:21966? Is it build id?

Right now I am using: httpAuth/app/rest/builds?locator=buildType:
In this I cant find any timestamp.

Comment: I am not looking for a specific build but all builds in a project.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to make additional calls for each build, but you need to craft how you want the response returned. There's a query string parameter called **fields** that lets you define what you want to bring back.

e.g. to return the start and finish data in your original call you can add **&fields=build(startDate,finishDate)** to your original request

```
/httpAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/id:##BUILD_TYPE_ID##/builds?fields=build(startDate,finishDate)
```

This would return something like this

```
<builds>
  <build>
    <startDate>20140202T230456+0000</startDate>
    <finishDate>20140202T230518+0000</finishDate>
  </build>
  <build>
    <startDate>20140202T224912+0000</startDate>
    <finishDate>20140202T224957+0000</finishDate>
  </build>
</builds>
```

The caveat to this is that you now have to exclusively define what you want returned. So to return all the other fields and the start / finish date, add this parameter to the query string

```
&fields=build(id,buildTypeId,number,status,state,branchName,defaultBranch,href,webUrl,buildTypeId,startDate,finishDate)
```

TeamCity documentation - [Full and Partial responses](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/REST+API#RESTAPI-FullandPartialResponses)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

After you GET `/app/rest/builds?locator=buildType:...`, you need to get the detailed data of all the individual build runs you're interested in. That, unfortunately, means an extra REST call for every individual build.

The URL for each build will be in the form `/app/rest/builds/id:21966`, but don't hard-code this in your program. Instead, as you loop through all the builds (returned by your first call), take each build's `href` attribute and GET that.

To summarise:
* GET `/app/rest/builds?locator=buildType:...` once
* for each build in the returned data set, take its `href` and make another REST call
* for each returned build detail, the timestamps are in the following sub-elements: `queuedDate`, `startDate`, `finishDate`, `triggered`

We've tried implementing a dashboard this way before but found it unacceptably slow (too many REST calls). There is an alternative, which is to write a TC plugin (use the native OpenAPI): that will be much faster but of course it's more work.

Comment: So there is no way to get the timestamp and all the builds?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isn't; you have to look at the individual builds.